# Subquery and nested query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with an *operation* and an *amount* columns.
The *opearation* is an ENUM with two values: "in", "out".
*amount* is just an INT.

I would like to sum the amounts "in" and subtract
the sum of the amounts "out" in a single query.

I can extract a single value at a time:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as total_in
FROM movements
WHERE operation like "in"
```

but I have no idea how to do both in one query...

Comment: Can you share sample input data and expected output?

Comment: You can look into `GROUP BY` and aggregate functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Please test this: (CTE-Common Table Expressions):

```
WITH cte1 AS (SELECT SUM(amount) AS total_in FROM movements WHERE operation = "in")
,cte2 AS (SELECT SUM(amount) AS total_out FROM movements WHERE operation = "out")
SELECT *, (total_in - total_out) as difference FROM cte1 JOIN cte2;
```

If we test it with some fake data:

[image: FD]

Comment: I didn't know about CTE, interesting. As far as your query, is almost identical to mine. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: Hi @IDK, Yes! Not a big difference. For me, CTE's are very important topic to learn in sql, together with window functions; because It gives you amazing flexibility to solve challenging problems. You can learn more about CTE's here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, here it is:

```
with deposits as (
     select sum(amount) as total_deposits
     from movements
     where operation like "deposit"),
    withdrawals as (
         select sum(amount) as total_withdrawals
         from movements
        where operation like "withdrawal")
select (withdrawals.total_withdrawals - deposits.total_deposits ) as net_profit
from deposits cross join withdrawals;
```